# Tab bar activity taking to much time to load

Tags: android, kotlin, tabbar

'i have two activity A and B . A is normal activity and activity B have a tab bar which have 5 fragment. activity transaction using intent. when try to transaction From activity A to activity B , activity B taking to much time to load

> viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager)
> tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
> val myViewPageStateAdapter: MyViewPageStateAdapter =
> MyViewPageStateAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
> myViewPageStateAdapter.addFragment(fragmentVoice, getString(R.string.voice))
> myViewPageStateAdapter.addFragment(fragmentInternet, getString(R.string.internet))
> myViewPageStateAdapter.addFragment(fragmentCom, getString(R.string.combo_bundle))
> myViewPageStateAdapter.addFragment(fragmentSms, getString(R.string.sms))
> viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
> viewPager.adapter = myViewPageStateAdapter
> tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true)

'